# Page Specific JS Not working in Ruby On rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on using JS scripts in rails app.I am beginner and learning ruby on rails  and getting the below error.Can you plz help me to get rid of this error?
I have pasted the contents of related files for this issue.
Thanks in advance.

### **Error**

```
Webpacker can't find showboards.js in /home/punisher/Desktop/git/billboard/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
```

**webpacker.yml:**

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  additional_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

**app/JavaScript/packs/showboaards.js:**

```
alert("I am an alert box!");
```

**app/JavaScript/packs/application.js:**

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

**app/view/showboards.erb.html**

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'showboards' %>
```

Comment: There are a couple of typos: "showbooards" => "showboards", "JavaScript" => "javascript". Apart from that, it could be that you just need to restart your webpack server

Comment: Your answer is appreciated.Btw these typos came during copy paste.

Comment: I am getting following error:                                                                           [Webpacker] Compiling...
[Webpacker] Compilation failed:
/home/punisher/Desktop/git/billboard/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:93
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@rails/webpacker'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (/home/punisher/Desktop/git/billboard/node_modules/v8-

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60491830/error-cannot-find-module-rails-webpacker-rails-6                                                                                                               Trying this.Hope it work.